# Finding the whole word and if it does exist then replacing it

Tags: javascript, regex

I m trying to find the word in a text and if it does exist than replace it. But the problem is i guess regex because it sees the words for example "%!hello!%" like "hello". And also it doesnt find the word in text. Any suggestions ?

```
scriptPanel.setValue = function (oldValue,newValue) {
    var re = new RegExp("\\b" + oldValue + "\\b","g");

    var patt= sincapp.codeEditor.getValue().test(re);

    if(patt){
        var newText = sincapp.codeEditor.getValue().replace(re,oldValue);
        sincapp.codeEditor.setValue(newText);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You're replacing it with the same variable which you used for finding it. Also, you don't need to have a test before replacing, as it's just redundant.

```
scriptPanel.setValue = function(oldValue, newValue) {
    var re = new RegExp("\\b" + oldValue + "\\b", "g");
    var newText = sincapp.codeEditor.getValue().replace(re, newValue); // new value!!!
    sincapp.codeEditor.setValue(newText);
};
```

Comment: yeah i tried but still got the problem " it sees the words for example "%!hello!%" like "hello"" it doesnt see the "%!:.." as a part of a word..

Comment: @TolgaTamer I didn't get you.

Comment: @TolgaTamer yes, because word boundaries are used. If you don't want word boundaries, then just do `var re = new RegExp(oldValue,"g")`

Comment: but i need the word boundaries as well. I mean i need to replace the whole "%hello%"

Comment: Then do `var re = new RegExp("[^a-z]+\\b" + oldValue + "\\b[^a-z]+", "g")`

Answer (score 0):

Use this one:

```
var re = new RegExp("(?:^|\\s)" + oldValue + "(?:\\s|$)","g");
```

Comment: @TolgaTamer: may be you have to double escape: `\\s`.

Answer (score 0):

that example worked for me ;

```
RegExp("(^\|[ \n\r\t.,'\"\+!?-]+)(Čemšeniško)([ \n\r\t.,'\"\+!?-]+\|$)", "i")
```